# combining two dataframes just based on the rows, without considering respective index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1`, and `df2` respectively

```
        A1             A2
0       0.001       0.002
1       100           200
2       0.3           0.4

  

         B1           B2
86      0.0002       0.003
12       0.2          0.3
123     -0.001       0.000
```

Due to their generation mechanism them, their indexes are not matched, and one of the dataframes was not even indexed orderly. I need to just combine these two dataframes regardless of index, the expected result is as follows.

```
        A1          A2         B1        B2
0     0.001       0.002      0.002      0.003
1      100         200        0.2        0.3
2      0.3         0.4      -.0.001     0.000
```

In other words, I just need to combine them based on the row orders. I tried
`Pd.concat([df1,df2],index=1,ignore_index=True)`   or `pd.DataFrame([df1,df2])`. Neither works.

Comment: `pd.concat(..., axis=1, ...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True),
               df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

        A1       A2      B1     B2
0    0.001    0.002  0.0002  0.003
1  100.000  200.000  0.2000  0.300
2    0.300    0.400 -0.0010  0.000
```